# Quicksort vs Radix-sort

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo, quicksort

Eu gostaria de saber o porque *Quicksort* é mais difuso do que *Radix-sort*. Uma vez que o *quicksort* usa como base para o ordenamento a comparação e *radix-sort* não o segundo pode ser mais rápido que O(***n***log(**n**)), e na verdade é O(**mn**) onde **m** é o numero de bits utilizado para representar o elemento.

Porque não é mais difuso, especialmente para ordenação de números? Tem algo a ver com caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **Quicksort** é mais **flexível** e funciona bem com todos os tipos de dados, tudo o quê você precisa para ordenar é a possibilidade de comparar itens. É trivial com números, mas pode ser usado com outros tipos de dados também.

Já o Radix-sort, ordena as coisas por sua representação binária, ele nunca compara itens uns contra os outros.

Outro fator desta difusão é que, como você mesmo deu a ideia, o **Radix-sort** normalmente **necessita de mais memória**. Pois geralmente ele utiliza um buffer secundário para armazenar resultados parciais do algoritmo de ordenação. Em grandes quantidades de dados, isso pode gerar uma grande perda de performance.
Lembrando que a utilização de memória dependerá da quantidade de bits utilizados a cada "ordenação", onde o mesmo pode superar outros algoritmos.